# Почему глобальный объект не существует внутри функции вызванной обработчиком события?

Tags: javascript, объекты, javascript-events

Функция, записанная в свойство объекта, вызывается другими функциями, но внутри функции, вызванной событием, становится не видна. Даже если обратится к глобальной переменной явным образом, и не только функция но и в целом объект.

```js
var doc;

doc = {
  obj: document,
  width: function() {
    return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  },
  height: function() {
    return document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  }
}

function test() {
  alert(window.doc.width() + '' + document.documentElement.clientWidth);
}

function mainSize() {
  test();
}

test();

window.addEventListener('resize', mainSize);
```

Comment: Код вашего примера отрабатывает. Пробовали так: `window.addEventListener('resize', mainSize());` ?

Comment: Тут скобки не к чему( на всякий случай попробовал, функция не вешается на событие вообще.)

Comment: Запустил ваш код в `codepen` - при ресайзе выкидывает алерт, всё работает. Это часть какого-то кода, или прямо вот так у вас и не работает?

Comment: Так и должно быть, первый алерт при запуске скрипта показывает, что объект doc существует. Посл ресайза должен выскочить второй алерт, который должен показать что объект существует внутри события.

Пробовал ещё вот такие конструкции 
window.onresize=function(doc){main_size(doc)};

Comment: Как вы написали в комментарии - так оно и отрабатывает. Сразу при открытии алерт и при каждом ресайзе алерт. Что именно у вас не работает?

Comment: Все верно. Я тупица.